# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userData') when trying to pass data using context api with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to pass the UserData from the App component to dashboard component via context api.But when it redirects to /dashboard it gives me the error that TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userData').I've been trying to solve the issue but i have been unsuccessful.Can anyone help me with it?
Here is my app.js

```
function App() {
  // const [pageData, setPageData] = useState({});
  const [userData , setUserData] = useState({});
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const handleLogin = (res) => {
    // update the state of the App component with the received data
    console.log(res);
    setUserData(res);
    // you can do whatever you want with the received data here
  };




  return (
    <div className="App">
  <UserContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userData, setUserData}}>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          isLoggedIn ? (
            <Navigate to="/dashboard" />
          ) : (
            <Login setLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} handleLogin={handleLogin} />
          )
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </UserContext.Provider>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my dashboard component:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const {userData} = useContext(UserContext);

  const page = ["Home", "Logout"];
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)"); // check if screen size is below 600px
  console.log(userData.username , userData.password);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setSidebar(!sidebar);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
      <Navbar pages={page} />
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
          {isMobile && (
            <Button style={{ margin: "8px" }} onClick={handleToggle}>
              Toggle Sidebar
            </Button>
          )}
          {!isMobile && <Sidebar />}
          {sidebar && isMobile && <Sidebar />}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <Typography variant="h5">Dashboard</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} >
              <Typography variant="h3">Welcome back! {userData.username}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
              <Paper elevation={3} sx={{height:"15rem",width:"35rem"}}>
                <Typography variant="h6" >
                  Your Current Business Ventures
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1">
                  None
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1" >
                  {userData.username}
                </Typography>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

I tried a few online solutions but werent of any use

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating your context using `React.createContext()`, then the initial state of `context` is `undefined`, which means `userData` is undefined briefly.

In your example, to see `userData` just ignore when it's `undefined` initially using a `?` before the any properties on the undefined object.

`console.log({ username: userData?.username, password: userData?.password });`

Comment: I tried the solution you provided by adding                                                     
`console.log({
    username: userData && userData.username,
    password: userData && userData.password
  });`;   but it still gives me error on the line :  `const { userData } = useContext(UserContext);`

Comment: That's because you can't destructure something that is `undefined`. You need to use `const context = useContext(UserContext);` --- Check if `context` is `undefined` or not, then destructure.

Comment: i dont understand tho why it is undefined as i update it as soon as i login.I beleive i have used the context hook in the right way.Am relativately new to using context api.Sorry to bother u again.Here is my login component `const Login = (props) => {const setUserData}=useContext(UserContext);  
  const loginHandler=(e)=>{
      axios     .post("http://localhost:8000/app/login", userDetails)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Success", res);
        setUserData(res.data);
        props.setLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error", err));      
  };`

Comment: What does your createContext() code look like to start? I’m sure it’s empty.

Comment: const UserContext = createContext();  should I initialise them inside createContext()